# Is it normal for wireless speeds on a mobile device to be slower than the speed on a laptop?

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, iphone

Both my laptop—a Retina MacBook Pro—and phone—an iPhone 6—support 802.11ac wireless and my router, an AirPort Time Capsule, also support 802.11ac wireless.

The speed I get on laptop is about 70 to 80 Mbps but the speed I get on the phone is between 10 to 35 Mbps. So I was wondering if it is an issue with the devices?

Comment: @JakeGould Yes, iPhone was showing on 802.11 b/g .. but Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently there are a lot of folks having issues with IOS 8 and slower than expected WiFi speeds. Here are a couple things you can try:

Disable Wi-FI Networking Services at > Privacy > Location Services > System Services. This only relates to your location being used for Wi-Fi Networking, so it doesn’t disable Wi-Fi entirely.

Reset Network Settings. Resetting these settings flushes caches and clears DHCP settings and other networking related info. To reset network settings, open the Settings app and navigate to Settings > General > Reset and tap on Reset Network Settings.

Source: http://www.iphonehacks.com/2014/09/fix-ios-8-wifi-problems.html

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference links, as the answer can become invalid if the linked pages changes or the target sites are unreachable/permanently offline.

Comment: Thanks, David! Would the information in my answer be more appropriate as a comment?

Comment: No, answer is fine :)

Comment: Wow that first thing was like 10x speedup. Thanks!